# International texts from Lumia 640 to Galaxy s6

Tags: lumia

My husband and I were texting freely between Ecuador and the US when I was using my Lumia 520 and he has a Samsung s6. I use ATT gophone.

My lumia 520 broke and I bought a Lumia 640. Now, I can get messages from his Samsung, but he doesn't get mine. My messages are going through, he just isn't getting them.

I called ATT and they assured me I have access and if I'm getting a time on my message then it is being sent.

I spent 2 hours troubleshooting his Samsung and my Lumia.  He has not accidentally blocked me (we checked), or blocked international.  I have all of my settings correct (according to tech who was a US tech) and his company assured him he is good.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Can other people / phones in the US and Ecuador receive your texts?